# Изменить частоту подписи координаты Х на графике matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, графики

В даатфрейме есть некоторая колонка `modelDate`, которая сожержит различные даты, начиная с 1936 года. Я хочу построить график, который показывает количество вхожений каждой даты, т.е. по *Х* идет дата по *У* количество дат в датасете. Для этого написал код:

```
plt.bar(
    main_df.modelDate.value_counts().index, 
    main_df.modelDate.value_counts()
)
plt.show()
```

показывает все верно (все столбцы по кажой дате). однако даты пишутся не все, а с шагом в 20 лет. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можно ли как-то сделать шаг отображения дат меньшим, т.е 10 лет например. PS. в официальной документации не нашел параметра к *pyplot.bar()*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте перед plt.show() задать в явном виде количество тиков:

```
plt.xticks(np.arange(main_df.modelDate.value_counts().index.min(),
                     main_df.modelDate.value_counts().index.max()+10,
                     10))
```

Comment: То, что нужно, спасибо